# Why "!!" is required when converting the readline string value into int

Tags: kotlin, casting, readline

I am new to kotlin, and I have been doing research on the syntax of the language. It is to my understanding that in kotlin you can cast data types using integrated functions like :

```
.toInt()
```

converting 3.14 to an integer :

```
3.14.toInt()
```

since it is known that the `readline()` function returns a string i am not sure why this syntax is correct:

```
fun main() {
    println("please enter a int:")
    val num1 = readLine()!!.toInt()
    println("one more")
    val num2 = readLine()!!.toInt()

    println("sum : ${num1 + num2}")
}
```

and this syntax is incorrect

```
fun main() {
    println("please enter a int:")
    val num1 = readLine().toInt()
    println("one more")
    val num2 = readLine().toInt()

    println("sum : ${num1 + num2}")
}
```

returns the error:

```
 Error:(5, 26) Kotlin: Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type String
```

Just looking for a bit more of an explanation on casting and how the syntax differs when it comes to the `readline()` function and functions alike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `readLine()` returns a `String?` - the question mark means it can either be `null` or a `String`. In Kotlin, you need to handle instances with nullable type with either `?` or `!!` when you're invoking a method onto that instance.

The difference is that `?` only proceeds when the instance is not null, and `!!` forces it to proceed. The latter may give you a `NullPointerException`.

For example:

```
val num1 = readLine()?.toInt()
// Here, num1 could either be a String or null

val num1 = readLine()!!.toInt()
// if it goes to this next line, num1 is not null. Otherwise throws NullPointerException
```

Comment: Now i understand , so if i got what your saying correctly: readline() returns a string or null  which is unacceptable for the .toInt function because it only accepts strings as input ? so by using the !! it automatically declares that num1 isn't of type null

Comment: @RonComputing Yep that's correct. If `toInt()` also accepts a nullable string, then you don't have to use either `?` or `!!`. You can just invoke it directly with `readLine().toInt()`

Answer (score 1):

readLine() returns String? (nullable version of String?) 
Function toInt() receives String (non-nullable type).

```
fun String.toInt(): Int   // non-nullable
fun String?.toInt(): Int  // nullable (call)
```

You must do some kind of a null check to be sure that toInt will called on a non-nullable object. The !! operator converts nullable String? type to non-nullable String.